# Graphical Timer Format

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a timer that is displayed on my `JFrame`, but my problem is that I can't format the timer to look right. The timer is being displayed on a canvas so I am using graphics2D to display it.

Is there a quick way to format it or do I have to put a bunch of if statements?

### Code

```
private Graphics2D graphics;

private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
private int minutes = 0, seconds = 60;

// Draws the timer.
public void drawTimer() {
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 26));
    graphics.drawString(minutes + ":" + seconds, getWidth() / 2, 35);
}

// Part of the timer.
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds == -1) {
            seconds = 60;
        }
    }
}
```

When I want the timer to start I just call:

```
timer.start();
```

I would like it to look something like:

1:00,
0:59,
0:58,
etc.

Comment: See things like [`String.format(String,Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) & [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).. *"can't format the timer to look right."*  Define 'right'?  What do you expect to see?

Comment: `public void drawTimer() { graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);`  This implies the code has cached a `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` object, when it should have gone about painting 'on demand' instead.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).